# Problems making GET request from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I'm trying to make an HTTP GET request using the jQuery `get()` function, but I'm having some trouble.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
// get the links on the page
var pageLinks = $.find('#pageLinks');
// loop through each of the links
$(pageLinks).find('a').each(function(){
   if($(this).attr('title') !== "Next Page"){
       // make a GET request to the URL of this link
   $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
           console.log("here");
           var temp = parse_page(data);
           // concatenate the return string with another
           bdy = bdy+String(temp);
           console.log("done");
       });
   }
});
```

There are multiple pages that I need to get data from. Since the `get()` function is asynchronous, I get the pages in a random order. Secondly, the concatenation does not work. Even though I get each of the pages, they're not put into `bdy`.

Can anyone suggest how I might deal with this?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: As far as the synchronization issue goes, why not chain the callbacks using jQuery deferring?

Comment: `bdy` is defined right before the code I've shown you. 
`String(temp)` converts `temp` into a `string`. Without it, I kept getting warnings from Chrome.

Comment: @JesseB I'm very new to jQuery (I started yesterday), and I was hoping someone would point out what I could do. Could you link to some explanation of what deferring is?

Comment: @efficiencyIsBliss I actually think using a queue might be easier in this case.  I have some untested code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6tvTD/2/) that I wrote for another question that should give you a head start on synchronizing the AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that there are modules that allow one to manage the control flow in JS. The ones I found are:

- [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async#series/%22async%22)
- [Step](https://github.com/creationix/step)

For help using the above modules, see my follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810825/using-async-parallel-along-with-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Construct `bdy` after all pages are retrieved, i.e. store `get` results in a dictionary or array; wait for all `get`s to finish; then assemble them in the correct order.

Comment: I thought of that, but I feel like there should be some built-in way of doing this, which is what I'm hoping to find out here

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one and it works:

```
// get the links on the page
var pageLinks = $('a');
var bdy 
// loop through each of the links
$(pageLinks).each(function(){
console.log(this);
       // make a GET request to the URL of this link
           $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {

           // concatenate the return string with another
           bdy = bdy + data.toString();
           console.log(bdy);
       });

});
```

Comment: I get the same results with this code as I was getting before.

Answer (score 0):

As an example of what @muratgu has said:

```
var results = [];
var count = 0;

function allDone() {
    var bdy = results.join("");
    // do stuff with bdy
}

// get the links on the page
var pageLinks = $.find('#pageLinks');

// filter the links so we're left with the links we want
var wantedLinks = $(pageLinks).find('a').filter(function (idx) {
    return $(this).attr('title') !== "Next Page";
});

// remember how many links we're working on
count = wantedLinks.length;

// loop through each of the links
wantedLinks.each(function (idx) {
    // make a GET request to the URL of this link
    $.get($(this).attr("href"), function (data) {
        console.log("here");
        var temp = parse_page(data);
        results[idx] = temp;

        // Decrement the count.
        count--;

        if (count === 0) {
            // All done.
            allDone();
        }
    });
});
```

You could go further and abstract this into a data type that can perform N async downloads, and then notify you when all are complete.