# Using async.parallel along with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, get

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568417/problems-making-get-request-from-jquery) some time about about working with async calls in JS. The answers there did not help me, but later on I found out about modules that would solve my problems, for example [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#series).

The thing is, I don't know how to use these modules yet (I'm a noob at JS) and I was hoping that someone would be able to point me in the right direction here. Specifically, I'd like to know how to use the `async.parallel`.

The function that I'm trying to get executed in parallel is the success callback function of a `jQuery get()` call, as shown below:

```
$.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
     temp = parse_page(data);
     var el = page_num.split(" ");
     pages[el[el.length-1]] = data;
});
```

The problem I'm having is that the number of these `get()` calls that I would need to do is variable.

How would I go about putting these variable number of function calls in an array and then use that array with `async.parallel`?